# Generics for RecyclerView.Adapter Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, kotlin-extension

I am trying to use a common extension function for all `RecyclerView.Adapter` in my app so I created an ext fun called notifyAdapter, But it is not working as expected.

```
fun <T> RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>.notifyAdapter() {
    updateAll()
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

When i use

`offlineListAdapter.notifyAdapter()` or `onlineListAdapter.notifyAdapter()`

it throws

> Cannot be applied to receiver OfflineListAdapter

OfflineListAdapter.kt

```
    class OfflineListAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<OfflineListAdapter.OfflineListHolder>() {

      class OfflineListHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

      }
    }
```

How can I create a common extension function for all `RecyclerView.Adapter` using Generics.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this.

1. You can mark the `ViewHolder` parameter with `out` variance. This way your function isn't generic, so you won't have access to the exact type of the `ViewHolder` in it.

   ```
   fun RecyclerView.Adapter<out RecyclerView.ViewHolder>.notifyAdapter() {  ...  }
   ```
2. Alternatively, you can have a generic type parameter for the function that's bound to be a subclass of `ViewHolder`. This way you can use `T` inside the function, for example, you could create a `listOf<T>()` if you wanted to.

   ```
   fun <T : RecyclerView.ViewHolder> RecyclerView.Adapter<T>.notifyAdapter() {  ...  }
   ```
3. Finally, you could also use star projection, which I believe in this case will give you the exact same result as the first solution, since the type argument of the `Adapter` class has an upper bound of `ViewHolder`.

   ```
   fun RecyclerView.Adapter<*>.notifyAdapter() {  ...  }
   ```

You can read in more detail about variance and projections in the offical documentation [here](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html).